# Where do the intrinsic parities of particles come from?

Tags: particle-physics, conservation-laws, standard-model, conventions, parity

It is known that some particles have negative [intrinsic parity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrinsic_parity) - for example pion $\pi$. I was wondering if this parity can be understood. I read somewhere that parity of quarks is defined to be positive and parity of antiquark is negative. This explains parity of pion, but then question arises: why does the antiquark have negative parity?

Edit:

I followed the link provided by Qmechanic and it lead me to information that structure of parity transformations for fermions is determined by Dirac equation. In book by Bjorken and Drell one can find information that parity operator for a fermion takes form $$ (P \psi)(t, \vec x)= e^{i \phi} \gamma^{0} \psi (t, - \vec{x}), $$ where phase $\phi$ is arbitrary. One can choose it to be such that parity is $1$ for all fermions and this implies that it must be $-1$ for antifermions. I will be grateful if someone is kind enough to confirm whether this is all there is to it.

Comment: More on [intrinsic parity](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+%22intrinsic+parity%22).

Comment: Just a suggestion: In the case of a Dirac field, the concept of intrinsic parity is related to both the $P$ and $C$ transformations. From the standard choice for the representation $C:~\psi(t,\vec{x})\mapsto i\gamma^2\psi^*(t,\vec{x})$ and $P:~\psi(t,\vec{x})\mapsto\gamma^0\psi(t,-\vec{x})$ one can confirm that $P^2=C^2=1$ and $CPC^{−1}P^{−1}=−1$. It is from this commutator of $C$ and $P$ that intrinsic parity arises.